# Importing text file in DXL script?

Tags: python, scripting, mapping, ibm-doors

I am looking for a solution which helps to import a text file in the code, I am doing this to remove the hard coded values. Instead, I would want to call a text file and read values, which does the mapping. Making the code independent of projects. Any Idea how to do it ?

```
OleAutoObj createWrapperObj(Object obj) {
OleAutoArgs args = create
OleAutoObj wrapper = null
print oleMethod(d2e, "CreateObjectWrapper", args, wrapper)

olePut(wrapper, "ModuleName", name(m))
olePut(wrapper, "aObjectType", unicodeString(obj."aObjectType"))
olePut(wrapper, "TestDescription", unicodeString(obj."Object Short Text"))
olePut(wrapper, "TestPictureName", unicodeString(obj."ID"))
olePut(wrapper, "TestFocus", unicodeString(obj."Test_Focus"))

return wrapper }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file with each parameter you want to read on its own line.
Here is an example of how to read the file.

```
string filename="C:/parameters.txt" // can also use relative paths
Stream input = read filename
string param
input >> param //this reads the first line into the string param

//... continue to input into each variable
//... and then when all done

close input
```

I think this is what you are asking for.